# Print enotez list without section number

Tags: graphics, bibliographies, numbering, enotez

I want to remove the section number from my list of figures' heading that functions as image bibliography. I use a kind of strange `enotez` construct to generate this list (since I have to fill strange requirements).

Is there a solution as simple as `\section*{}` for normal sections?
[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@book{example-reference,
    keywords={figure},
    author={Doe, John},
    title={An Image},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[toc=listofnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


%bibliography
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

%endnotes
\usepackage{enotez}
\renewcommand*\enotezwritemark[1]{[{#1}]}
    \setenotez{
    list-name={List of figures}
    }
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}{
    heading = \section{#1},
%    notes-sep = \baselineskip,
    format = \normalfont,
    number = {[#1]}
    }



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{example-image}
        \caption{This is an example image. \endnote{\fullcite{example-    reference}}}
    \label{fig:example-reference}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

%\printbibliography[title=Bibliography,notkeyword=figure]
\pagebreak
\printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```

Normally, it prints every item only a single time, but I seem to have messed it up while creating a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. In `DeclareInstance`, change `heading = \section{#1}` to `heading = \section*{#1}`.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that was too easy. I really could have seen it myself. Thanks anyway :-)